# How pass values from db to activity?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, pie-chart

I have this (EDIT):

```
   public class ExpensesDataSource {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DBHelper helper;

    public ExpensesDataSource(Context context) {
        helper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() {
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        database.close();
    }

    public List<Expense> getAllExpenses() {
        open();
        Cursor all_cursor = database.query(EXPENSES_TABLE, new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, KEY_DESC,
                KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE);
        List<Expense> allExpenses = new ArrayList<Expense>();

        if (all_cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            while(!all_cursor.isLast()) {
                Expense expense = new Expense();
                expense.setId(all_cursor.getInt(all_cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
                expense.setDescription(all_cursor.getString(all_cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESC)));
                expense.setAmount(all_cursor.getFloat(all_cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT)));
                expense.setDate(all_cursor.getInt(all_cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
                allExpenses.add(expense);
                all_cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        close();
        return allExpenses;
    }

    public float getTotalExpense() {
        open();
        Cursor sum_cursor = database.query(EXPENSES_TABLE, new String[]{"SUM("+KEY_AMOUNT+")"}, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        sum_cursor.moveToFirst();
        float total = sum_cursor.getFloat(0);
        sum_cursor.close();
        close();
        return total;
    }

    public long insertItem(String desc, Float amount, long date) {
        open();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
        args.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        long id = database.insert(EXPENSES_TABLE, null, args);
        close();
        return id;
    }

    public void deleteItem(long id) {
        open();
        database.delete(EXPENSES_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
        close();
    }

    public void updateItem(Long rowId, String desc, Float amount, long date) {
        open();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
        args.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        database.update(EXPENSES_TABLE, args, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        close();
    }

    public void deleteAllItems() {
        open();
        database.delete(EXPENSES_TABLE, null, null);
        close();
    }

    public void flipItem(long id) {
        open();
        Cursor amount_cursor = database.query(EXPENSES_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_AMOUNT},
                KEY_ID+"="+id, null, null, null, null);
        amount_cursor.moveToFirst();
        float amount = amount_cursor.getFloat(0);
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_AMOUNT, -amount);
        database.update(EXPENSES_TABLE, args, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
        close();
    }

    public Expense getById(long rowId) {
        open();
        Cursor row_cursor = database.query(EXPENSES_TABLE, new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, KEY_DESC,
                KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_DATE}, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId , null, null, null, null);

        if(row_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Expense expense = new Expense();
            do {
                expense.setId(row_cursor.getInt(row_cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
                expense.setDescription(row_cursor.getString(row_cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESC)));
                expense.setAmount(row_cursor.getFloat(row_cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT)));
                expense.setDate(row_cursor.getInt(row_cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
            }  while(!row_cursor.isLast());
            close();
            return expense;
        }

        close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and i need pass the value `amount` in my grafico activity:

```
  public class grafico extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.piegrafico);
    PieGraph pg = (PieGraph)findViewById(R.id.piegraph);

    PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
    slice.setValue(20);
    pg.addSlice(slice);
    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
    slice.setValue(10);
    pg.addSlice(slice);
    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AA66CC"));
    slice.setValue(2);
    pg.addSlice(slice);     

    pg.setOnSliceClickedListener(new OnSliceClickedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(int index) {

        }

    });


}

private void setUpViews() {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String desc = extras.getString(DBHelper.KEY_DESC);
        Float amount = extras.getFloat(DBHelper.KEY_AMOUNT);
        long date = extras.getLong(DBHelper.KEY_DATE);

}
```

}

As you can see i've tryied to written:

```
private void setUpViews() {

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            String desc = extras.getString(DBHelper.KEY_DESC);
            Float amount = extras.getFloat(DBHelper.KEY_AMOUNT);
            long date = extras.getLong(DBHelper.KEY_DATE);

    }
```

But really i don't know if it's correct.. I need insert `amount` for example here:

```
PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
        slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
        slice.setValue(amount); //here
```

but i can't do it.. How can i solve? Thanks

Comment: have you read this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html ? Do you have datasource class? Usually queries and inserts are done via datasource's methods.

Comment: So what have i to do exactly?

Comment: you have to create a model class - class that will represent your table's structure e.g. Expense with fields similar to that you add to the database. Then you should create a datasource class that will manage insert, delete and quering (one Expense and list of all Expenses in table). After that you can write sth like this: Expense expense = datasource.getExpenseByPrimaryKey(key); PieSlice... ; slice.setValue(expense.getAmount());

Comment: well i have another class with the cursor

Comment: then consider using that class. dbhelper is used only in datasource (class with cursor) and contains constants a-la table and column names, database name and version and so on. datasource (or class with cursor) manages all interactions with db.

Comment: yes perfectly.. Infact this is my DataSource class.. But now, how can i procede? i've tryied `Expense expense = ExpencesDataSource.getExpenseByPrimaryKey(KEY_AMOUNT);` and then `slice.setValue(expense.getAmount());` but i get errors.. what is wrong?

Comment: did you create an Expense class? and is KEY_AMOUNT a primary key for table's row? i mean in sql table primary key.

Comment: expense class it's already created... and in there there is : `public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }`

Comment: (1) you are trying to get amount field from bundle extras of the intent. if you didn't put it in the bundle in previous activity it wouldn't be in the bundle (2) getById fillins in cycle only one expense and returns the last one.

Comment: I'm totally in crysis... :( please can you help me? What have i to write?? I get an error : `Expense expense = ExpensesDataSource.getFloat(KEY_AMOUNT);` in getFloat.. I can't understand sorry

Comment: well. i think the problem is in the datasource class. please see http://pastebin.com/LsWWGzuN (it's part of my project).

Comment: can't you write sth similar to  public float getTotalExpense() for amount or amount is each expense's property?

Comment: ExpensesDataSource.getFloat(KEY_AMOUNT) can't have static member getFloat. you can make getAmount and iterate through all table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40564/discussion-between-david-d-and-margarita-litkevych)